# Initialize a Sieve of Eratosthenes in Scala

Tags: scala, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am learning Scala while solving some exercises and I am currently solving an exercise where I need to initialize a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

I am using the following code:

```
  val sieve = Array.fill[Boolean](100)(true)

  for (p <- 2 until sieve.length if sieve(p) && math.pow(p, 2) <= sieve.length) {
    for (i <- p * 2 until sieve.length by p) {
      sieve(i) = false
    }
  }
```

I see some problems with this approach, for example, the outer loop still evaluates all numbers from some Y until sieve.length to test the condition `sieve(p) && math.pow(p,2) <= sieve.length`, although the code inside the loop is not executed for those values of `p`.

I think this could be solved with the following code:

```
 var p = 2
 while(math.pow(p, 2) <= sieve.length)
 {
   if(sieve(p))
     for (i <- p * 2 until sieve.length by p)
       sieve(i) = false

   p += 1
 }
```

I may be wrong, but I think I am complicating too much.

What's a good way to initialize a Sieve of Eratosthenes using Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many other ways of writing a Sieve of Eratosthenes in Scala. Regarding this particular code, the for-comprehension is better written as:

```
val sieve = Array.fill[Boolean](100)(true)

for {
  p <- 2 until sieve.length 
  if sieve(p) && math.pow(p, 2) <= sieve.length
  i <- p * 2 until sieve.length by p
} sieve(i) = false
```

Also,

> the outer loop still evaluates all numbers from some `Y` until
>   `sieve.length` to test the condition `sieve(p) && math.pow(p,2) <=
>   sieve.length`,

You could compute the square root too, though that's an expensive computation. You can use `takeWhile` to avoid it:

```
p <- 2 until sieve.length takeWhile (x => x * x < sieve.length)
```

Also, the starting place of the final loop can be improved:

```
i <- p * p until sieve.length by p
```

Altogether, you get this:

```
val sieve = Array.fill[Boolean](100)(true)

for {
  p <- 2 until sieve.length takeWhile (x => x * x < sieve.length)
  if sieve(p)
  i <- p * p until sieve.length by p
} sieve(i) = false
```

Now, I wouldn't use booleans for this, nor an `Array`. Instead, my preferred implementation (for efficiency) uses `BitSet` instead. For example:

```
val last = 100
val numbers = 2 to last
val sieve = collection.mutable.BitSet(numbers: _*)
for (p <- numbers takeWhile (x => x * x <= last) if sieve(p))
  sieve --= p * p to last by p
```

There are other implementations I value for their functional nature, but I'll leave that to others.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could pass a {} block to a for like that.
How about the _* you used to initialize the BitSet, where is that documented?

Comment: @simao you'll probably find that documented where varargs are discussed. It is just a wa of saying that the sequence elements are the parameters, instead of the sequence itself being one parameter.

Comment: ah! so i guess it's like python's *args and **kwargs syntax. Thanks!